# Hide Twitter Bootstrap left and right arrows if only one slider is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to hide the Bootstrap Carousel left and right buttons if only one slider is present but can't seem to get it to work properly.

I've tried

```
    if ($('.carousel-inner div').length === 1 ) { 
        $(this).find('.controls .carousel-control').hide();
    }
```

and

```
    if($('.carousel-inner .item').is(':only-child')) {
    $(this).find('.controls .carousel-control').hide();
```

Without any luck.

Is there a particular reason why neither of these would work? The console returns the correct number of sliders for `.length` and I use the exact same `.hide` method on a different function dealing with this carousel.

Comment: what is `$(this)` referencing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `$(this).find(...).hide();` try `$('.controls .carousel-control').hide();`

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I read "what is `$(this)` referencing" it came to me. Your answer ultimately was the solution.

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer works fine so long as you have 1 carousel per page. I had a couple so thought I'd add to the solution:

Based on using the standard Bootstrap Carousel Mark up:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

You'll want to iterate through each occurrence of a carousel, use $(this) and grab its siblings:

```
$('.carousel-inner').each(function() {

    if ($(this).children('div').length === 1) $(this).siblings('.carousel-control, .carousel-indicators').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for Bootstrap 4+

```
$('.carousel-inner').each(function() {

if ($(this).children('div').length === 1) $(this).siblings('.carousel-indicators, .carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next').hide();

});
```